# Error while loading an assembly into a new AppDomain

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies

I tried the below code to load and unload managed assemblies.

```
AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some");     
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
assemblyName.CodeBase = pathToAssembly;
Assembly assembly = dom.Load(assemblyName);
Type [] types = assembly.GetTypes();
AppDomain.Unload(dom);
```

however, i got an exception "Friendlyname or appdomainbase invalid
", while loading the assembly into the appdomain. 
Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

As the exception implies - it's just that it can't find the assembly.

You need to need to use the [AppDomainSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx) type when creating the AppDomain and set the `ApplicationBase` to the folder where you want it to probe for assemblies when using the `Load` method.  You can also set the `PrivateBinPath` as well for additional paths.

[This other MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8hk0245%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (linked from the previous one) gives an example.

Providing a `CodeBase` in the AssemblyName will not work.